# plone.app.event- Using IEventBasic as a behavior, how can I properly set the end field programatically in an event?

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I have a dexterity content type (my.product.myobject) that uses the IEventBasic behavior (implemented in the xml file with other behaviors) and I'm trying to make the end field be set within the same week of the start field.  I attempt to correct the end date in an IObjectAddedEvent (zope.lifecycleevent.interfaces.IObjectAddedEvent).

I first get the week range from the start field:

```
def getWeekRangeFromDate(a_date,offset=1):
    start = (a_date - timedelta(days=(a_date.weekday() + offset) % 7)).replace(hour=0,minute=0)
    end = (start + timedelta(days=6)).replace(hour=23,minute=59)
    return {'start':start,
            'end':end,
           }
def myObjectAdded(myObject, event):
    week_range = getWeekRangeFromDate(myObject.start)
    if myObject.end > week_range['end']:
        myObject.end = week_range['end']
```

I have the end field printed in the browserview and I use IEventAccessor to extract the end date from the myObject:

```
class View(BrowserView):
    def __init__(self,context,request):
        ...
        self.context = self.context

    def getFormattedEnd(self):
        if self.context.whole_day == False:
            return IEventAccessor(self.context).end.strftime('%m/%d %I:%M %p')
        ...
```

When it doesn't need to be programmatically corrected, the end field displays correctly, but when it does, it appears 5 hours off.

In my myObjectAdded event, I tried:

```
if myObject.end > week_range['end']:
    myObject.end = week_range['end'] - timedelta(hours = IEventAccessor(myObject).end.offset().total_seconds()/3600)
```

This does appear right actually, but when I go to the edit form and change the start field, the end field ends up changing itself seemingly random.  Changing the starting hour field to 16 changed the end's month about two weeks ahead.

How can I set it without it acting up?  Am I misundertanding how to use IEventBasic?

Edit:  I'm coming across something really interesting.  In the edit form, the Start End Validator is failing.

Event Starts - 25/November/2016 9:00
Event Ends - 25/Novermber/2016 20:00

I click submit and the status message says End date must be after the start date.

Edit: The version of Plone I am using is 4.3.

Comment: That reminds me of issues I saw in early versions of Plone 5.  I'd recommend trying latest versions of Plone 5.0 and plone.app.event for starters

Comment: I'm using Plone 4.3 and unfortunately at this stage of the project I'm working on, I can't switch to 5 just yet.

Comment: Ok, is your plone.app.event version the latest?